# DB Access Error During TestLink Installation

Tags: testing, installation, testlink

Am new to testlink. I was just creating testlink installation with xampp with my localhost.During installation of testlink .I got this below error

```
 ============================================================================== 
     DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
     ============================================================================== 
    #0  database->exec_query() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:852]
    #1  tlEvent->writeToDB() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:986]
    #2  tlDBLogger->writeEvent() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:548]
    #3  tlTransaction->writeEvent() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:469]
    #4  tlTransaction->add() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logging.inc.php:68]
    #5  tLog() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\database.class.php:208]
    #6  database->exec_query() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:705]
    #7  tlEventManager->deleteEventsFor() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:132]
    #8  tlLogger->deleteEventsFor() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:215]
    #9  renderLoginScreen() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:198]
    #10 doBlockingChecks() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:34]
     ============================================================================== 
     ============================================================================== 
     DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
     ============================================================================== 
    #0  database->exec_query() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:705]
    #1  tlEventManager->deleteEventsFor() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\lib\functions\logger.class.php:132]
    #2  tlLogger->deleteEventsFor() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:215]
    #3  renderLoginScreen() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:198]
    #4  doBlockingChecks() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\login.php:34]
     ==============================================================================
```

I googled a lot but i could not find the suitable answer. Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issues using following steps.
Used proper credentials for mysql (username,password) and used the same for testlink installation.

If your credential is correct and till you are facing the same issues then following steps.

1. Navigate to the \testlink-code-testlink_1_9\install\sql\mysql folder and open file 'testlink_create_tables.sql'
2. Modify creation_ts datetime NOT NULL default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as creation_ts datetime NOT NULL default '2016-11-30 11:26:36'.
3. There should not be two column with default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. If available change the default value '2016-11-30 11:26:36' instead of 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
4. Provide proper database credential and proceed. Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. I had mysql installed with credentials
username:"root" and password:   (blank) ,
when i had used same credentials for testlink installation using xampp . 
Had got this error "DB Access Error" . 
Finally i uninstalled both mysql and xampp .

Used valid credentials for mysql (instead of using "blank" for  password) 
and used the  same credentails for testlink installation using xampp.

So this was caused due to "Database login credentials"